# connection refused when I connect postgresql using java

Tags: java, postgresql, connection

I use spring-boot to connect the postgresql database.

I run my java app on the same machine with the postgresql databse.

My application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/dbname
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=passwd
```

I use the `JdbcTemplate` and apache's dbcp `BasicDataSource`.

postgresql.conf:

```
listen_addresses = 'localhost'
```

pg_hba.conf:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            sha256
```

Because I only connect db from localhost, so I think the configuration is ok.

But I got the following connect refused exception.

```
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: **Connection refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.**. Well?

Comment: @CraigRinger hostname and port are ok。 But how to check that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections?

Comment: Try connecting with `psql` using the same options you used in PgJDBC. `psql` understands JDBC URLs, so `psql 'jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/dbname'`.